# is there's a way to design my own twitter, facebook, google plus buttons?

Tags: facebook, twitter, google-plus

Hello is there a way to design my own `twitter, facebook, google plus` buttons? I need to make those buttons using my custom style. I don't want to use the standard buttons available. What is the function to get the share count for facebook (So I can use it anywhere else)?

Answer (score 1):

**Sure!**

```
echo  ' <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=',$my_url,'"> 
<img  src="'.$folder.'/facebook.png" width="50"   alt=""></a>  
<a href="http://twitter.com/home?status=',$my_url,'">  <img
src="'.$folder.'/twitter.png"  width="50" alt=""></a>  ';
```

*$folder is your custom icon folder AND $my_url is your url*

Comment: And where is the function to get the share count ?

Comment: he can just replace the variable with the string and not use the echo command (plain html - of course without the apostrophes).

Answer (score 1):

Google+ allows for custom buttons, so long as they meet our branding guidelines.

https://developers.google.com/+/branding-guidelines

Answer (score 0):

A function to use anywhere else

```
function myshare($folder, $my_url){
return
'<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='.$my_url.'"><img src="'.$folder.'/facebook.png" width="50" alt=""></a>
<a href="http://twitter.com/home?status='.$my_url.'"><img src="'.$folder.'/twitter.png"  width="50" alt=""></a>
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url='.$my_url.'" ><img src="'.$folder.'/google.png"  width="50" alt=""></a>
';
}

echo myshare('myfoldername','myurl');
```